# calculating factorial with modulus for large range gives overflow

Tags: math, factorial

i tried to calculate the factorial for a range of integers (2<=n<=10^7) and under a modulus as follows:

```
MAXN = 10000000
typedef unsigned long long ULL;
ULL MOD =  109546051211ULL;
ULL factorial[MAXN+1];

void preFact()
{
    factorial[0] = factorial[1] = 1;
    int i;
    for(i = 2;i<=MAXN;i++)
    {
        ULL temp = factorial[i-1]%MOD;
        ULL temp2 = i%MOD;

        temp = (temp*temp2)%MOD;
        factorial[i] = temp;
    }
    printf("%llu %d\n",factorial[i-1],i);
}
```

However the above print statement gives value = 0 . In fact for all n >=587117 i get value of factorial[n]%MOD as 0 . I can't get where is the overflow and how to correct it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There is no overflow, the result is correct.

```
109546051211 = 186583 * 587117
```

so for all `n >= 587117`, we have `n! % 109546051211 = 0`.

Comment: Can you explain how it is zero? some how it is not very intuitive to me.

Comment: The modulus is the product of two distinct primes here, let's say `m = p*q` with `p,q` primes and `p < q`. Then for every `n >= q`, we see that `n! = 1*2*...*p*...*q*...*n` contains both, `p` and `q`, as factors, so `n!` is a multiple of `p*q = m`, i.e. `n! % m` is `0`.